# Calculate difference from previous week in Spotfire cross table

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I want to calculate the difference from present to previous week in Spotfire cross table. Difference I want to calculate is the cumulative difference between present to previous week (Newly Added in week).
Here is my example data
[image]

and the expected output table is

[image]

Please help me to solve to create this in Spotfire cross table

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find the exact solution you want using a cross table, but there are possible alternatives.

1 - use your existing Cross Table (Horizontal: Week, Vertical: ID and Status) to show the Totals (Grand total for columns) and then you get your Newly Added in week row (although I don't understand why your first cell is null, as judging from the Cumulative Sum I thought it would be 4).

2 - add a Waterfall Chart with [Week] on the X axis. You can colour by [ID] or [Status] or both.

This reacts to filtering.

You could go via calculated columns instead, but they would not react to filters:

1 - first calculate [Weekly Count] as

```
Count() over ([Week])
```

2 - then calculate [Cumulative Sum] as

```
Sum(case when Rank(rowid(),[Week])=1 then [Weekly count] end) OVER (AllPrevious([Week]))
```